# How can I prove/understand the following functional derivative?

Tags: greens-functions, functional-derivatives

Assume that $F[h(\xi);x,y]$ be the inverse of $G[h(\xi);x,y]$ in the sense that the following identity is satisfied:
\begin{equation}
\int dz F[h(\xi);x,z]G[h(\xi);z,y] \equiv \delta(x-y)
\end{equation}
for any $h(\xi)$. Then one can obtain:
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\delta}{\delta{h(z)}}F[h(\zeta);x,y] =
-\int d\xi d\eta F[h(\zeta);x,\xi]\dfrac{\delta G[h(\zeta);\xi,\eta]}{\delta{h(z)}}F[h(\zeta);\eta,y]
\end{equation}
**Question**:How can I prove/understand this functional derivative?

Note: This functional derivative appears in [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02725962). [APPENDIX A:(A.7)]

Comment: This is done [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/401868).

Comment: Thanks for your help.