# How to derive the vertex function from mass operator in Hedin's equations?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, many-body, greens-functions

I am stuck from the mass operator to vertex function in the derivation of Hedin's equations. The problem could be organized as follows:

1. Mass operator:
   $$M(1,2)=i\hbar\int d(34)v(1^+,3)\dfrac{G_1(1,4)}{\delta U(3)}G_1^{-1}(4,2)$$
   with $1=(x,t)$, $U$ is the external perturbation and $G_1$ is the single particle Green's function.
2. The total classical potential $V$:
   $$V(1) \equiv U(1)-i\hbar\int d3v(1,3)G_1(3,3^+)$$

Regarding alternatively $G_1$ as the functional of $V$ instead of $U$ and using chain rule and the following relation
$$\dfrac{\delta F[h(\zeta);x,y]}{\delta h(z)}=-\int d\xi d\eta F[h(\zeta);x,\xi]\dfrac{\delta F^{-1}[h(\zeta);\xi,\eta]}{\delta h(z)}F[h(\zeta);\eta,y]$$
one can derive
$$M(1,2)=-i\hbar\int d(345)v(1^+,3)G_1(1,4)\dfrac{\delta G_1^{-1}(4,2)}{\delta V(5)} \dfrac{\delta V(5)}{\delta U(3)} \tag{1}$$
from which one can introduce the vertex function
$$\Gamma(1,2,3)\equiv \dfrac{\delta G_1^{-1}(1,2)}{\delta V(3)}=\delta(1,2)\delta(1,3)+\dfrac{\delta M(1,2)}{\delta V(3)} \tag{2}$$

How can I prove the equation $(1)$ and derive the equation $(2)$?

[This problem is related to this paper. [(3.16)--(3.17)]](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02725962)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Quick hint: Use [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/401868) followed by [functional chain rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235769/is-there-a-chain-rule-for-functional-derivatives) to get Eq. (1). Now observe $G_{}^{-1}(1,2)=G_{0}^{-1}(1,2)-V(1)\delta(1,2)-\Sigma(1,2)$ to get Eq. (2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have gone through all the details.

**The first part:**

Chain rule:
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\delta G_1(1,4)}{\delta U(3)}
=
\int d5
\dfrac{\delta G_1(1,4)}{\delta V(5)}
\dfrac{\delta V(5)}{\delta U(3)}
\end{equation}

Functional identity:
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\delta G_1(1,4)}{\delta V(5)}
=
-\int d67
G_1(1,7)
\dfrac{\delta G_1^{-1}(7,6)}{\delta V(5)}
G_1(6,4)
\end{equation}

Insert them into the mass operator:
\begin{align*}
M(1,2)
&
=
-
i\hbar \int d34
v(1^+,3)
\int d567
G_1(1,7)
\dfrac{\delta G_1^{-1}(7,6)}{\delta V(5)}
G_1(6,4)
\dfrac{\delta V(5)}{\delta U(3)}
G_1^{-1}(4,2) \\
&
=
-
i\hbar \int d3567
v(1^+,3)
G_1(1,7)
\dfrac{\delta G_1^{-1}(7,6)}{\delta V(5)}
\dfrac{\delta V(5)}{\delta U(3)}
\delta(6,2) \\
&
=
-
i\hbar \int d357
v(1^+,3)
G_1(1,7)
\dfrac{\delta G_1^{-1}(7,2)}{\delta V(5)}
\dfrac{\delta V(5)}{\delta U(3)}\\
&
=
-
i\hbar \int d345
v(1^+,3)
G_1(1,4)
\dfrac{\delta G_1^{-1}(4,2)}{\delta V(5)}
\dfrac{\delta V(5)}{\delta U(3)}
\end{align*}

**The second part:**

The inverse single-particle Green's fucntion:
\begin{equation*}
G_1^{-1}(1,2)
=
G_1^{(0)-1}(1,2)
-
U(1)
\delta(1,2)
-
\Sigma(1,2)
\end{equation*}

The external potential $U$:
\begin{equation*}
U(1) = V(1)+i\hbar \int d3 v(1,3)G_1(3,3^+)
\end{equation*}

The self energy:
\begin{align*}
\Sigma(1,2)
=
\Sigma_H(1,2)
+
M(1,2)
\end{align*}

Hartree self-energy:
\begin{align*}
\Sigma_{H}(1,2)
=
-
\delta(1,2)
i \hbar
\int d3 v(1,3) G_1(3,3^+)
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
&
\Gamma(1,2;3)
\equiv
-
\dfrac{\delta G_1^{-1}(1,2)}{\delta V(3)}
=
-
\dfrac{
\delta
\left[
G_1^{(0)-1}(1,2)
-
U(1)\delta(1,2)
-
\Sigma(1,2)
\right]
}{\delta V(3)}\\
&
=
0
+
\delta(1,2)
\dfrac{\delta U(1)}{\delta V(3)}
+
\dfrac{\delta \Sigma_H(1,2)}{\delta V(3)}
+
\dfrac{\delta M(1,2)}{\delta V(3)}\\
&
=
\delta(1,2)\delta(1,3)
+
\delta(1,2)
i \hbar \int d3 v(1,3) \dfrac{\delta G_1(3,3^+)}{\delta V(3)}
-
\delta(1,2)
i \hbar \int d3 v(1,3) \dfrac{\delta G_1(3,3^+)}{\delta V(3)}
+
\dfrac{\delta M(1,2)}{\delta V(3)}\\
&
=
\delta(1,2)\delta(1,3)
+
\dfrac{\delta M(1,2)}{\delta V(3)}
\end{align*}

Comment: Looks like you are double counting Hartree self energy by including it both in $U$ and $\Sigma$?

Comment: @Sunyam Hartree self-energy appeared only in $\Sigma$, $U$ is viewed as the external perturbation term to using the functional derivative technique and can be diminished in the last stage by taking $U \rightarrow 0$.